# How to create record in match pattern

Tags: f#

I want to write an application that read ip address from xml file. The file looks like

```xml
<range>
    <start>192.168.40.1</start>
    <end>192.168.50.255</end>
    <subnet>255.255.255.0</subnet>
    <gateway>192.168.50.1</gateway>
</range>
```

I create an records type to save the ip address

```
type Scope = { Start: IPAddress; End: IPAddress; Subnetmask: IPAddress; Gateway: IPAddress }
```

I wrote a unit function, that output the ip's.

```
loc
            |> Seq.iter (fun e -> match e.Name.LocalName with
                                    |"start" -> printfn "Start %s" e.Value
                                    |"end" -> printfn "End %s" e.Value
                                    |"subnet" -> printfn "Subnet %s" e.Value
                                    |"gateway" -> printfn "Gateway %s" e.Value
                                    | _ -> ())
```

How can I return the scope records type instead of unit?

Comment: So what part are you stuck on?

Comment: I stuck on, how to return the record type scope in the match pattern. I have no idea, how to do that.

Comment: So how would you normally construct a record? - the hint here is using `with` and `Seq.fold`

Comment: It might be a lot easier to do this using the XML type provider: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [XML type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) makes this a lot easier. You can just point it at a sample file, it will infer the structur and let you read the file easily:

```
type RangeFile = XmlProvider<"sample.xml">
let range = RangeFile.Load("file-you-want-to-read.xml")

let scope = 
  { Start = IPAddress.Parse(range.Start)
    End = IPAddress.Parse(range.End)
    Subnetmask = IPAddress.Parse(range.Subnet)
    Gateway = IPAddress.Parse(range.Gateway) }
```

That said, you can certainly implement this yourself too. The code you wrote is a good start - there is a number of ways to do this, but in any case, you'll need to do some lookup based on the local name of the element (to find start, end, etc.).

One option is to load all the properties into a dictionary:

```
let lookup = 
   loc
   |> Seq.map (fun e -> e.Name.LocalName, IPAddress.Parse(e.Value)
   |> dict
```

Now you have a lookup table that contains `IPAddress` for each of the keys, so you can create `Scope` value using just:

```
let scope = 
  { Start = lookup.["start"]; End = lookup.["end"];
    Subnetmask = lookup.["subnet"]; Gateway = lookup.["gateway"] }
```

That said, the nice thing about the XML type provider is that it removes the need to do lookup based on string values and so you are less likely to make mistakes caused by typos.

Comment: I did it as you mentioned above, but the compiler says `The field, constructor or member 'Subnet' is not defined` and `Type constraint mismatch. The type XmlProvider<...>.Ip is not compatible with type Scope`.

Comment: What do you get when you type `range.` ? Type providers should give you completion and you should see what is available...